# Is $(A \oplus B)^{\perp} = A^{\perp}\cap B^{\perp}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is this true?

$$(A \oplus B)^{\perp} = A^{\perp}\cap B^{\perp}$$

I am trying to prove this, but could not find a way.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A,B \subset A \oplus B$ you have $(A \oplus B)^\perp \subset A^\perp, B^\perp$. This shows $\subset$.

To prove $\supset$ just explain what it means for $x \in A^\perp \cap B^\perp$.

Comment: Why does $A,B \subset A + B$? $A,B$ may not be subspaces.

Comment: @U2647 Direct sum is usually defined for subspaces. Anyhow, if they are not subspaces, you simply use the fact that $C^\perp= (Span(C))^\perp$. And then $A, B \subset Span(A \oplus B)$.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to remember that the inner product is linear in the first variable, i.e. that $$<u + v, w> = <u,w> + <v, w>.$$

If you are thinking of the special case of the dot product, we have that $$a \cdot (b+c) = a\cdot b + a\cdot c.$$

Suppose that $w$ is a vector that is perpendicular to both $u$ and $v$. Then we have that $<u,w> = 0 = <v,w>$ by the definition of perpendicular. Therefore $$<u+v, w> = <u,w> + <v,w> = 0.$$